# Why List<int>.Remove() method removing entries from the calling method's list?

Tags: c#, list

Pardon me if its a very foolish question. But I want to know why this is happening.

My code is

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> lst = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
            {
                lst.Add(i);
            }

            List<int> lstRet = lst;
            List<int> lstRet2 = lstReturn(lstRet);
         }

        static List<int> lstReturn(List<int> lst)
        {
            List<int> NewList = lst;
            NewList.Remove(3);
            NewList.Remove(6);
            NewList.Remove(9);

            return NewList;
        }
```

The problem is after the method `lstReturn(lstRet);` is getting called, both the list Values values are same, as if `lst` and `lstRet2` both are identical List.

Why it is like that. Can anybody please explain? Is only one copy of List is created, if yes, why?

I am again saying if its a duplicate, pardon me, I searched but didn't get any satisfactory answer.

Thanks

Edit:
The question was not a duplicate, the solution lies elsewhere, may be the fundamental knowledge is same. Instead passing the same list `lst` to `lstRet`, if its like

`List<int> lstRet = New List<int>(lst)`

this solved the problem, Thanks to all of you for such a quick response.

Comment: The list is copied by reference. So you are modifying the same list.

Comment: Reference passing (Different names for the same object)

Comment: Why are the answers being downvoted without comment?

Comment: @ChrisShain Stop making assumptions. I rarely downvote.

Comment: Why down voted, I told that I didn't have idea why its happening. Instead of down voting if somebody explains would be good for me and for others as well,  not everybody is Einstein.

Comment: And I don't know why the answers *are* downvoted. Considering they are correct.

Comment: I didn't downvoted any answers, all are giving some kind of light to my little knowledge. Thanks to all of you.

Comment: @LewsTherin There's this practice on SO when people use downvoting to prod others to delete answers that the downvoters dislike for any reason. I do not think it's a good practice, but it exists nevertheless.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yeah I've noticed. And consider it distasteful. But I promise you that although mad.. I am innocent in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
List<int> lstRet = lst;
```

It does not do what you want it to do - instead of copying the list, it copies the reference. You have only one list, from which the items get removed.

If you wish to make a copy, replace the line above with

```
List<int> lstRet = new List<int>(lst);
```

Comment: Thanks it really helps me. This is what I actually missed, Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same list.  You are assigning the return value of `lstReturn` to the variable `lstRet2`:

```
List<int> lstRet2 = lstReturn(lstRet);
```

and the function lstReturn returns the list that was passed in:

```
static List<int> lstReturn(List<int> lst)
    {
        List<int> NewList = lst; // NewList now is the list that was passed in

        // snip...

        return NewList;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer and explanation is beautiful but I can mark only one answer as accepted. @Chris